# How to create scrollbar in QtQuick 2.0?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I am trying to create a scrollbar in QtQuick 2.0,

I found that `Scrollbar` component is available in QtQuick 1.0 but I can't find such component in QtQuick 2.0. How can I create scrollbar for `ListView` in QtQuick 2.0?

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

ScrollBar/ScrollIndicator is easy to do, and the code would be identical in QQ1 or QQ2 (except the import) :

///////// ScrollBar.qml //////////////

```
import QtQuick 2.0;

Item {
    id: scrollbar;
    width: (handleSize + 2 * (backScrollbar.border.width +1));
    visible: (flickable.visibleArea.heightRatio < 1.0);
    anchors {
        top: flickable.top;
        right: flickable.right;
        bottom: flickable.bottom;
        margins: 1;
    }

    property Flickable flickable               : null;
    property int       handleSize              : 20;

    function scrollDown () {
        flickable.contentY = Math.min (flickable.contentY + (flickable.height / 4), flickable.contentHeight - flickable.height);
    }
    function scrollUp () {
        flickable.contentY = Math.max (flickable.contentY - (flickable.height / 4), 0);
    }

   Binding {
        target: handle;
        property: "y";
        value: (flickable.contentY * clicker.drag.maximumY / (flickable.contentHeight - flickable.height));
        when: (!clicker.drag.active);
    }
    Binding {
        target: flickable;
        property: "contentY";
        value: (handle.y * (flickable.contentHeight - flickable.height) / clicker.drag.maximumY);
        when: (clicker.drag.active || clicker.pressed);
    }
    Rectangle {
        id: backScrollbar;
        radius: 2;
        antialiasing: true;
        color: Qt.rgba(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.85);
        border {
            width: 1;
            color: "darkgray";
        }
        anchors { fill: parent; }

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent;
            onClicked: { }
        }
    }
    MouseArea {
        id: btnUp;
        height: width;
        anchors {
            top: parent.top;
            left: parent.left;
            right: parent.right;
            margins: (backScrollbar.border.width +1);
        }
        onClicked: { scrollUp (); }

        Text {
            text: "V";
            color: (btnUp.pressed ? "blue" : "black");
            rotation: -180;
            anchors.centerIn: parent;
        }
    }
    MouseArea {
        id: btnDown;
        height: width;
        anchors {
            left: parent.left;
            right: parent.right;
            bottom: parent.bottom;
            margins: (backScrollbar.border.width +1);
        }
        onClicked: { scrollDown (); }

        Text {
            text: "V";
            color: (btnDown.pressed ? "blue" : "black");
            anchors.centerIn: parent;
        }
    }
    Item {
        id: groove;
        clip: true;
        anchors {
            fill: parent;
            topMargin: (backScrollbar.border.width +1 + btnUp.height +1);
            leftMargin: (backScrollbar.border.width +1);
            rightMargin: (backScrollbar.border.width +1);
            bottomMargin: (backScrollbar.border.width +1 + btnDown.height +1);
        }

        MouseArea {
            id: clicker;
            drag {
                target: handle;
                minimumY: 0;
                maximumY: (groove.height - handle.height);
                axis: Drag.YAxis;
            }
            anchors { fill: parent; }
            onClicked: { flickable.contentY = (mouse.y / groove.height * (flickable.contentHeight - flickable.height)); }
        }
        Item {
            id: handle;
            height: Math.max (20, (flickable.visibleArea.heightRatio * groove.height));
            anchors {
                left: parent.left;
                right: parent.right;
            }

            Rectangle {
                id: backHandle;
                color: (clicker.pressed ? "blue" : "black");
                opacity: (flickable.moving ? 0.65 : 0.35);
                anchors { fill: parent; }

                Behavior on opacity { NumberAnimation { duration: 150; } }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To use it :

```
import QtQuick 2.0;

Rectangle {
    width: 400;
    height: 300;

    ListView {
        id: list;
        anchors.fill: parent;
        model: 100;
        delegate: Rectangle {
            height: 50;
            width: parent.width;
            color: (model.index %2 === 0 ? "darkgray" : "lightgray");
        }
    }
    ScrollBar {
        flickable: list;
    }
}
```

Enjoy !

Comment: Thank you very much ! Very flexible and efficient solution. The only thing it is missing is the horizontal orientation. Since ListView supports it, I will be adding a property binding to scroll horizontally

Comment: If we have interactive changing of the number of delegates, binding loop is detected for this:
`Binding {
        target: flickable;
        property: "contentY";
        value: (handle.y * (flickable.contentHeight - flickable.height) / clicker.drag.maximumY);
        when: (clicker.drag.active || clicker.pressed);
    }`

And the whole scrolling is broken then. We can scroll father then contentHeight. Can you, please, help with this?

Comment: It works, but spams "_QML Binding: Binding loop detected for property "value"_" to the log whenever I drag the handle. Any solution on this?

Comment: Very useful, thanks. But I get the same binding loop warning.

Comment: Good solution but I've noticed that the scrollbar position become wrong when elements are dynamically inserted into the list (in my case at the top).

Answer (score 12):

Loved the solution by TheBootroo (+1 for him!) but found his solution only few days ago, by following a comment to a recent question. 
Meanwhile, I've independently developed mine for a project I was working on and I'm going to share such a solution here. Hope it can be useful. :)

My scrollbar has a (sort of) "OS X feel" (intended) so e.g. it does not include scrolling arrows on the sides.

Here is the code:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
   id: scrollbar

    property Flickable flk : undefined
    property int basicWidth: 10
    property int expandedWidth: 20
    property alias color : scrl.color
    property alias radius : scrl.radius

    width: basicWidth
    anchors.right: flk.right;
    anchors.top: flk.top
    anchors.bottom: flk.bottom

    clip: true
    visible: flk.visible
    z:1

    Binding {
        target: scrollbar
        property: "width"
        value: expandedWidth
        when: ma.drag.active || ma.containsMouse
    }
    Behavior on width {NumberAnimation {duration: 150}}

    Rectangle {
        id: scrl
        clip: true
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        height: flk.visibleArea.heightRatio * flk.height
        visible: flk.visibleArea.heightRatio < 1.0
        radius: 10
        color: "gray"

        opacity: ma.pressed ? 1 : ma.containsMouse ? 0.65 : 0.4
        Behavior on opacity {NumberAnimation{duration: 150}}

        Binding {
            target: scrl
            property: "y"
            value: !isNaN(flk.visibleArea.heightRatio) ? (ma.drag.maximumY * flk.contentY) / (flk.contentHeight * (1 - flk.visibleArea.heightRatio)) : 0
            when: !ma.drag.active
        }

        Binding {
            target: flk
            property: "contentY"
            value: ((flk.contentHeight * (1 - flk.visibleArea.heightRatio)) * scrl.y) / ma.drag.maximumY
            when: ma.drag.active && flk !== undefined
        }

        MouseArea {
            id: ma
            anchors.fill: parent
            hoverEnabled: true
            drag.target: parent
            drag.axis: Drag.YAxis
            drag.minimumY: 0
            drag.maximumY: flk.height - scrl.height
            preventStealing: true
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the code to use it. All the fields are optional expect for the flickable, obviously. Values set are the default ones:

```
ScrollBar {
    flk: privacyFlick
    radius: 10          // Optional
    basicWidth: 10      // Optional
    expandedWidth: 20   // Optional
    color: "grey"       // Optional
}
```

Comment: +1 - Thanks so much for posting your solution! I was searching a simple always-visible scrollbar without background for a long time. There are some (alleged) solutions out there, but this is the first one that worked, even out of the box. And on top of that, it is very easy to adapt it to my own needs. Good work

Comment: footer and header is not considered in this scrollbar

Comment: You mean the arrows @MahdiKhalili? That is intended and implied in the description about the OSX feel, I guess.

Comment: its using anchors for positioning its not working as expected in listview because of footer and header i solved it with this https://docs.huihoo.com/qt/5.x/qtquick-customitems-scrollbar-example.html

Comment: Oh, I see now. Well, don't remember the details to be honest. But if you have fixed it yourself good.

Answer (score 11):

I think this will do the trick

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtquickcontrols/qml-qtquick-controls1-scrollview.html

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0
ScrollView{
    ListView {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This structure works as described, but note that only mouse navigation then works, keyboard navigation is disabled. See the QT bug reports [ScrollView breaks keyboard navigation in ListView](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-31976) and [Allow disabling of Mouse Interaction with ListView (Flickables?) while still retaining keyboard interaction](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-17051)

Comment: I thought this would help me a lot to get the scroller working. Unfortunately, some items are missing at the bottom when I have a grouped list.

Answer (score 4):

Qt 5.6 introduces new controls as the technical preview "Qt Labs Controls". Among other stuff, the controls introduce a built-in [`ScrollBar`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.6/qml-qt-labs-controls-scrollbar.html) type (interactive) and [`ScrollIndicator`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.6/qml-qt-labs-controls-scrollindicator.html) type (not interactive).

In Qt 5.7 new controls exited technical preview and are now renamed "Quick Controls 2", to stress the fact that they superseed the previous controls.

If you are using Qt 5.6, which is an LTS version and will be around for quite sometime, `ScrollBar` can be used as follows:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import Qt.labs.controls 1.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 600

    Flickable {
        anchors.fill: parent
        contentWidth: image.width
        contentHeight: image.height

        //ScrollIndicator.vertical: ScrollIndicator { }  // uncomment to test
        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar { }
        ScrollBar.horizontal: ScrollBar { }

        Image {
            id: image
            source: "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/tntOCGkgt98/maxresdefault.jpg"
        }
    }
}
```

Whereas in Qt 5.7 and onward you can use `ScrollBar` or `ScrollIndicator` as follows:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 600
    height: 300

    Flickable {
        anchors.fill: parent
        contentWidth: image.width
        contentHeight: image.height

        ScrollIndicator.vertical: ScrollIndicator { }
        //ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar { }       // uncomment to test    

        Image {
            id: image
            source: "http://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/92/9d/3d/929d3d9f76f406b5ac6020323d2d32dc.jpg"
        }
    }
}
```

Usage syntax is pretty much the same whereas a major refactoring occured in the styling code as can be seen in e.g. Labs Controls [`ScrollIndicator` customization page](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.6/qtlabscontrols-customize.html#customizing-scrollbar) in comparison to Quick Controls 2 [`ScrollIndicator` customization page](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-scrollindicator).