# qml gridview: special add item at the end

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I would like to have QML `GridView` with at the end of it a special element to add new items. So when the grid reflows that special element at the end reflows exactly like normal elements. I had it coded with a `Flow`, with inside a Repeater and after it, that special element and it worked great, but I can't get scrollbars with a Flow, so I moved to a GridView.

I tried the `footer` property of the GridView, but the footer appears under the grid, while I want it on the last row of the grid besides the other items.

To make it clear here is what I want:

```
[item1] [item2] [item3]
[item4] [ ADD ]
```

Also, the special element must have a different display an different action on click.

I would like the C++ side not to be aware of that special behaviour. If I must add an item at the end of the model, I would like it add it within the QML so that I don't taint the C++ with that implementation detail.

I tried this:

```
model: projects.push({name: '+'})
```

and also various types of `append`, but that didn't work.

Comment: "but I can't get scrollbars with a Flow" --> Exploiting `ScrollView` or a `Flickable` as a container for the `Flow`should provide the scrollbars. Is it not a feasible option?

Comment: I think `ScrollView` works only on `Flickable` which as far as I understand are only `GridView` and `ListView`? I started looking a bit more into it now. Failed previously.

Comment: The first effect I get when I add the `Flow` in add `ScrollView` is that the `Flow` flows only vertically. I remember previously I managed to get it to flow horizontally after some tweaking. But not to flow in two dimensions as it does without the `ScrollView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad to read that you solved the issue. 
After testing your code, I think you can achieve the same result in an easier way.

If you bind the `Flow` to the `Item` which contains the `ScrollView`, the `Flow` can grow horizontally and you got the vertical scrollbar as required. The working code:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
// import QtQuick.Controls 1.3      // <--- requires Qt >= 5.4

Window {
    id: container
    width: 300
    height: 150
    visible: true

    ScrollView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        //horizontalScrollBarPolicy:  Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff  // <--- requires .Controls 1.3

        Flow {
            width: container.width       // width of ScrollView parent
            spacing: 10
            Text { text: "Text"; font.pixelSize: 40 }
            Text { text: "items"; font.pixelSize: 40 }
            Text { text: "flowing"; font.pixelSize: 40 }
            Text { text: "inside"; font.pixelSize: 40 }
            Text { text: "a"; font.pixelSize: 40 }
            Text { text: "Flow"; font.pixelSize: 40 }
            Text { text: "item"; font.pixelSize: 40 }
            Text { text: "yeah"; font.pixelSize: 40 }
            Text { text: "alright"; font.pixelSize: 40 }
            Text { text: "cool"; font.pixelSize: 40 }
            Text { text: "almost"; font.pixelSize: 40 }
            Text { text: "not"; font.pixelSize: 40 }
            Text { text: "epic"; font.pixelSize: 40 }
        }
    }
}
```

Here, with Qt < 5.4, you got the horizontal scrollbar since the vertical one covers part of the content space. Using `controls 1.3` from Qt 5.4 (and the related commented code) solves the issue.

---

Another way to solve the problem is by using `Flickable` with custom scrollbars (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17833103/how-to-create-scrollbar-in-qtquick-2-0)). In this case the code would be:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

Window {
    id: container
    width: 300
    height: 150
    visible: true

    Flickable {
        id: flick
        anchors.fill: parent
        contentHeight: flow.height    // grows according to the size of the Flow

        Flow {
            id: flow
            width: container.width
            spacing: 10
            Text { text: "Text"; font.pixelSize: 40 }
            Text { text: "items"; font.pixelSize: 40 }
            Text { text: "flowing"; font.pixelSize: 40 }
            Text { text: "inside"; font.pixelSize: 40 }
            Text { text: "a"; font.pixelSize: 40 }
            Text { text: "Flow"; font.pixelSize: 40 }
            Text { text: "item"; font.pixelSize: 40 }
            Text { text: "yeah"; font.pixelSize: 40 }
            Text { text: "alright"; font.pixelSize: 40 }
            Text { text: "cool"; font.pixelSize: 40 }
            Text { text: "almost"; font.pixelSize: 40 }
            Text { text: "not"; font.pixelSize: 40 }
            Text { text: "epic"; font.pixelSize: 40 }
        }
    }

    ScrollBar {                 // one of the scrollbars from the linked question
        flickable: flick
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get scrollbars working based on a `Flow` as suggested by BaCaRoZzo.

However it's a bit complex scheme and I get QML warnings on stdout.

Here's how I did it:

```
ScrollView {
    anchors.fill: parent
    Flickable {
        contentWidth: parent.width
        contentHeight: flow.implicitHeight
        Flow {
            id: flow
            anchors.fill: parent
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

If I simply put the `Flow` in a `ScrollView` I get only one column in the flow.

This works as far as I can tell, however I get this warning on stdout:

```
QML Flickable: Binding loop detected for property "contentWidth"
```

I hope there's a simpler solution, but that's what I have for now...

*EDIT:* OK I got rid of the warning. I just set `width: parent.width` instead of `contentWidth` in the `Flickable` and it's ok, behaves well and no warnings. I guess I'll stick with that unless someone comes up with a nicer solution.

Comment: Yeah, you shouldn't use `anchors.fill: parent` in a container that doesn't have a fixed size but rather tries to fit its content.